# Doctrine2 NestedSet Extension: Rendering children nodes

Tags: php, doctrine

i am using [DoctrineExtensions\NestedSet](http://github.com/blt04/doctrine2-nestedset)

i am trying to render children nodes. i used

```
$node->getChildren();

array
  0 => 
    object(DoctrineExtensions\NestedSet\NodeWrapper)[218]
      private 'node' => 
        object(Application\Models\Post)[240]
          protected 'id' => int 3
          protected 'title' => string 'trying to use zend_auth' (length=23)
          protected 'body' => string 'hello world' (length=11)
          protected 'thumbnail' => string '' (length=0)
          protected 'dtPosted' => 
            object(DateTime)[252]
              ...
          protected 'dtLastAction' => 
            object(DateTime)[247]
              ...
          protected 'lft' => int 2
          protected 'rgt' => int 3
          protected 'root' => int 1
          protected 'user' => 
            object(Application\Proxies\ApplicationModelsUserProxy)[159]
              ...
          protected 'tags' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[233]
              ...
      private 'manager' => 
        object(DoctrineExtensions\NestedSet\Manager)[204]
          ...
```

i got an array of `NodeWrapper`s. i am trying to get my `Post` object from it. how do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

From a `NodeWrapper $n`, call `$n->getNode()` to get the item wrapped by the NodeWrapper.